# Kestrel How to pass data back to console app

Tags: c#, .net-core, kestrel

I created a console app in Net Core. I started a Kestrel web server by using

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseStartup<Startup>().Build().Run();
```

I want the web server to receive a web request (with some data) and then shut itself down with

```
applicationLifetime.stopApplication();
```

Now I want to pass that data back to the console app. Is it possible? If so, how do I do it.

Comment: What do you mean by "pass the data back to the console app"? What exactly do you want to do with data? Do you want to return it as the result of `Main`?

Comment: The whole thing is very strange. A web app that shut's itself down?! What are you trying to do?

Comment: The console app is actually going to be a library that does all kinds oauth related operations.

Comment: So, it should not start a web server. You either need to implement a separate oauth service (which starts a web server, and all the its interactions are through HTTP request/response), or a library that is loaded inside another app and encapsulates the desired logic (which does not start a separate server).

Comment: @MohammadDehghan Thank you for giving your insight. What you are talking about is the Oauth Server related stuff. I'm making a library for Oauth Client related desktop stuff. Do you know if it possible what I'm asking for? If you do, please answer the question

Comment: Although I'm sure you are doing something wrong, but here's one way to do this: Create a static property in your `Program` class. Set that property in your specific request, and read it in your `Main`, after the calling `Run` method.

Comment: Well, your solution works. Who would have thunked a solution would be so simple. If you read up on the Oauth spec/flow for desktop apps, you would see that, you need to spin up a web server temporarily to receive the authorization code. Again a huge thanks to you, you are a gentleman and a scholar.

Comment: You're welcome! Thanks for the info about Oauth. It seems logical! I didn't know that!